# Add path to URL

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

I have the following `scripts` object in my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "build-css": "node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./node_modules ./src/scss -o ./src/scss",
    "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./node_modules ./src/scss -o ./src/scss --watch --recursive",
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build-js": "react-scripts build",
    "build": "npm-run-all build-css build-js",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

My application is starting with `http://localhost:3000` on my local machine, and on my `NGINX` with the URL that I have configured.

I would like to have a path added to both URLs like this

`http://localhost:3000/subpath/` or for my server `{url}/subpath/`

Is there an easy way to do it? Some solutions I find looked unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: How about making a mapping for the host in /etc/hosts?

Comment: @ShubhamJain Could you please explain it in more detail? sorry I am ignorant about this topic.

Comment: so in your `/etc/hosts` file you can add mapping for your localhost. Something like `127.0.0.1       shubham.test.com`. What this does is now I can open shubham.test.com:3000 to run my server application? Is this something you were expecting or did I understood wrong?

Comment: I think this is not what I am looking for. When I start the app with `start` or when I build the app, it does not consider subpath like `/customPath/`. It will always run on the base path like `http://localhost:3000`. I simply always want to start it with a path added to the end like `http://localhost:3000/customPath`

Comment: You could route your application to custom route using react router

Answer (score 0):

You can do is redirect you base route to a custom URL in react router:

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Redirect from="/" to="customURL"/>
  <Route component={Layout} path="/">
    <Route component={Dashboard} path="customURL"/>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

This would redirect the base application from `/` to `/customURL`.

Let me know if this worked and if this is what were looking for!